# How to decrypt octal encoding from zfs diff output?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, zfs

`zfs diff` replaces some of the characters in files names with `\xxxx` (in an octal encoding). Can I decrypt it back with `awk` or `sed` or any other common utility (without resorting to a perl or a python script)? An example `zfs diff` output can be created as follows:

```
echo '+ F /dir/my\0040file' > listing
```

My question is, can I decrypt `listing` to get

```
+ F /dir/my file
```

instead of

```
+ F /dir/my\0040file
```

(My ultimate goal is to pipe it back in `ls -l` to get file sizes.)

Comment: Have you checked whether `zfs diff` has an option to return the raw filenames instead of escaping it?

Comment: @Barmar According to the man page, it does not.

Comment: Add `-e` to your `echo` command? See: `help echo`

Comment: @Cyrus, ah sorry. I might not have been clear in my question. I used echo just to make an example `listing`. In practice, that would be an output of a `zfs diff` command. So, I have `listing` just as given and I cannot create it in a different way.

Comment: Please add sample output from `zfs diff` (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus Actually, your comment was almost the solution. This works for me, `echo -e "$(<listing)"` If you feel like adding that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk since `strtonum()`:

```
$ echo '+ F /dir/my\0040file' | 
awk '{
    while(match($0,/\\0[0-9]{3}/)) {               # find \nnnn 
        c=strtonum(substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1))  # extract the nnnn
        printf "%s%c",substr($0,1,RSTART-1),c      # output
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)               # prepare for next round
    }
    print $0
}'
```

Output:

```
+ F /dir/my file
```

Pretty much tested only on your sample.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and dash):

```
sed 's/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

N.B. The version I use evaluates the RHS of the substitution command using /bin/sh which points to dash. The command `echo` in dash converts `\0nnn` to its octal representation.

Comment: I guess you meant `sed 's/.*/echo -e "&"/e' file`?